Are popular c compilers (gcc, clang, etc) not POSIX compliant?
Background
POSIX
The POSIX standard specifies what interface system utilities must have (amongst other things). For example, POSIX says that a conforming system must have a c compiler, and that it must use -I to include headers, etc.
Motivation
I created a lib which interfaces with C compilers, and I want to ensure that it will work with any c compiler, or at least those that are POSIX compliant.
Question
The POSIX standard says:
-G
    Create a shared library or create object files suitable for inclusion in such a shared library. Compilations shall be performed in a manner suitable for the creation of shared libraries (for example, by producing position-independent code). 
    ...

man gcc (v11) says:
       -G num
           Put definitions of externally-visible data in a small data section if that data is no bigger than
           num bytes.  The default value of num is 4 for any ARC configuration, or 8 when we have double
           load/store operations.

These two definitions for -G, unless I'm misunderstanding something, are entirely different.
What's going on here? Is gcc not POSIX compliant? Similarly for clang, which doesn't document a -G option, is clang also not POSIX compliant?
What's a POSIX compliant invocation for creating a shared object that also works with common c compilers?

POSIX 2024 is practically brand-new, and I suspect neither Linux nor macOS are jumping to implement it. Since, as you note, both gcc and clang already have -G flags, it's questionable if they ever will support the -G flag as defined by the POSIX standard. Both use -shared for this purpose instead - and I suspect you'll need to add an autoconf test (or equivalent in your build system) in order to figure out which one your compiler supports.

It's also possible that GCC and/or clang will add a POSIX compatibility mode if invoked as *c17, in which -G means -shared -fPIC as needed (and where presumably -std=c17 would be implicit). This would be a fairly reasonable thing to do, since POSIX has explicitly specified that the compiler be named c17 rather than cc. But to my knowledge neither compiler has done this yet.
